# Inheritance calling wrong Equals() method

Tags: c#, inheritance, equals

I have a question about overriding method `Equals`.

```
public class Asset
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Asset oAss = (Asset)obj;
        return Name == oAss.Name;
    }
}

public class Mortage : Asset
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Mortage oMor = (Mortage)obj;
        return this.Name == oMor.Name && this.Amount == oMor.Amount;
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mortage m1 = new Mortage();
        Mortage m2 = new Mortage();

        m1.Name = "House";
        m1.Amount = 2000;

        m2.Name = "Castle";
        m2.Amount = 200000;


        Asset a1 = m1;
        Asset a2 = m2;


        m1.Equals(m2);
        a1.Equals(a2);

    }
```

Why when I call the method `a1.Equals(a2)` this is the `Mortage.Equals()` which is called and not the `Asset.Equals()`?

Comment: Because the method Equals is overridden.

Comment: Because you've overridden the method in `Mortgage`, and the execution-time type of the object that `a1` refers to *is* a `Mortgage`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `m1` and `a1` are still the same instance of type `Mortgage`.

In this case the type system doesn't care what the variable type is, it uses the actual type to find the highest derived method that complies to the signature `bool (object)`, which is still `Mortgage.Equals` because it *overrides* the method from `Asset`. Marking the `Mortgage.Equals` method `new` would make that code call `Asset.Equals`.

Comment: Ok so how to call the Equals method from Asset ?

Comment: You don't. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: In my case, I have 4 classes: Direction, Department, Division and Sub Division. Each class inherites from the previous.

Comment: A user belong to an organisation, composed of the 4 classes above. And I would like use the Equals method from the Department to know if 2 users belong to the same department